# HTML deskDrawer not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, drawer

I'm using a desk drawer for my page when it's in phone. But for some reason when I try out the links inside the desk drawer on mobile, they won't work. I was hoping anyone could give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong.

Because it works when I try it on the computer on Chrome while simulating a phone browser but not in my phone's browser. The page is [www.bebe2go.com](http://www.bebe2go.com) and the desk drawer I'm using is this one: http://git.blivesta.com/drawer/fixed-navbar-left.

Here is the code for the navigator:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="drawer-header">
          <button type="button" class="drawer-toggle drawer-hamburger">
            <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="drawer-hamburger-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="drawer-main drawer-navbar-default">
          <nav class="container drawer-nav" role="navigation">
            <div class="drawer-brand hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="http://www.bebe2go.com/">Bebe2Go</a></div>

            <ul class="drawer-menu">
              {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
              {% assign child_list_handle = link.title | handleize %}
              {% if linklists[child_list_handle].links != blank %}
              <li class="drawer-menu-item dropdown drawer-dropdown-hover">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ link.title | escape }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="drawer-submenu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li class="drawer-submenu-item"><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title | escape }}</a></li>
                  {% for childlink in linklists[child_list_handle].links %}
                  <li class="drawer-submenu-item"><a href="{{ childlink.url }}">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</a></li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              </li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="drawer-menu-item"><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title | escape }}</a></li>  
              {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
            </ul>

          </nav>
        </div>

      </div>  
    </div>
```

Here is the link for the js: https://github.com/blivesta/drawer/blob/master/src/js/jquery.drawer.js

and here the link to the css:
https://github.com/blivesta/drawer/blob/master/dist/css/drawer.css

Comment: please post your code

Comment: it seems odd to have `position: relative;` on .drawer-navbar-default li, .drawer-navbar-default a, .drawer-navbar-default .drawer-brand

Comment: also try `https://hammerjs.github.io/` for better phone gestures. best of luck.

Comment: I tryed changing the posistion to other options but none of them work on mobile. D:

Comment: what javascript, did you write for this site? Please post it. You have an onclick conflict. You're loading 3 different types of jQuery on to the page. Could be it.